# Prevent function from being called

Tags: javascript, popup, settimeout

so I have a function to measure the connection speed, and I have that running every 10 seconds (no need to click anywhere).
In one of the conditions where speed is low, if it's true it calls other function that opens a pop-up with a message.
My problem is that, the speed function is called every 10 sec, so every 10 sec (if the speed continues low) it calls the pop-up, and I don't want that.

I want to call the pop-up the first time the speed is low, and only again 1 min after if it's still low.

My code is this :

```
 if (speedMbps < low) {
                
                //call the function to open pop-up
                popup_speedtest();
            }

...

function popup_speedtest() {
//make the pop-up opens in vbhtml
$("#alert_speedtest").modal('toggle');
}
```

I thought about doing this

```
setTimeout(function() {
//make the pop-up opens in vbhtml
$("#alert_speedtest").modal('toggle');
}, 60000);
```

but that doesn't let the pop-up open the first time, and also, every time the function runs that setTimeout reset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to track the state of having shown the modal.  Add a variable for something like that:

```
let shownModal = false;
```

Then when you show the modal, check and/or update the variable and set your 1-minute timer to reset the variable.  Something like this:

```
if (speedMbps < low) {
    if (!shownModal) {
        shownModal = true;
        popup_speedtest();
        setTimeout(function() {
            shownModal = false;
        }, 60000);
    }
}
```

That way it only performs the logic if the state is currently `false` and the logic is to set the state to `true`, show the modal, and set a timeout to return the state to `false`.